# Updating an existing "save layers to file" PS script

Tags: photoshop

I just downloaded a couple scripts to save layers in batch in photoshop. They both work well but for 1 of my specific purposes (saving with an overlay group for t-shirt mock ups) only 1 works well. The problem is it just saves each file with incremental numbers. I would prefer it to behave like the other script, which uses the layer name.

Could someone help me make that change? I have attached both scripts. I am hoping it would be as easy as taking a portion of the code from the one and putting it in the other. I just do not know how to do that. Thanks!

(her is the code that needs the layer naming function)

```js
// Name: Export Layers Inside Selected Group.jsx
// Description: Photoshop script that separately saves top level layers inside the selected group.
// https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/013a223e94ba0fb9a2a0

#target photoshop

try {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var docName = doc.name.split('.')[0];
}
catch (e) {
    alert( 'Open a document first...' );
}

function init() {

    var savefiles;

    dlg.g.saveAs.minimumSize.width = 463;
    dlg.btns.minimumSize.height = 142;


    dlg.btns.save.onClick = function(){
       savefiles = true;
       dlg.close();
       return savefiles;
    };

    dlg.show();

    if ( savefiles ){

        var getDestination = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select destination folder...', doc.saved ? doc.path : '' );
        var group = doc.activeLayer;
        var groupLength = group.layers.length;

        for( var i = 0 ; i < groupLength; i++ ){
            group.layers[i].visible = false;
        }

        for( var i = 0 ; i < groupLength; i++ ){

            var layer = group.layers[ i ];
            var layerIndex = i+1;

            layer.visible = true;

            save.file( dlg, doc, getDestination, layerIndex );

            layer.visible = false;

        }

        alert('Files Saved!');

    }

}

var save = {
    file: function( dlg, doc, getDestination, layerIndex ) {

        var saveOptions = {};
        var formats = ["psd", "pdf", "png", "jpg", "tiff"];

        for ( var i=0; i < formats.length; i++ ) {
            if ( dlg.g.saveAs[ formats[i] ].value ) {

                var fileformat = formats[i];

                var path = getDestination + "/" + fileformat;

                makeFolder( path );

                doc.saveAs( File( path + "/" + dlg.g.filename.filename.text + layerIndex ), save[fileformat](), true );

            }
        }

    },
    psd: function() {

        var psd_saveOpts = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();

        psd_saveOpts.layers = true;
        psd_saveOpts.embedColorProfile = true;
        psd_saveOpts.annotations = true;
        psd_saveOpts.alphaChannels = true;

        return psd_saveOpts;

    },
    pdf: function() {

        var presetName = '[High Quality Print]';

        var pdf_SaveOpts = new PDFSaveOptions();

        pdf_SaveOpts.pDFPreset = presetName;

        return pdf_SaveOpts;

    },
    jpg: function() {

        var jpg_SaveOpts = new JPEGSaveOptions();

        jpg_SaveOpts.matte = MatteType.WHITE;
        jpg_SaveOpts.quality = 10;
        jpg_SaveOpts.formatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;

        return jpg_SaveOpts;

    },
    png: function() {

        var png_SaveOpts = new PNGSaveOptions();

        png_SaveOpts.compression = 9;
        png_SaveOpts.interlaced = false;

        return png_SaveOpts;

    },
    tiff: function() {

        var tiff_SaveOpts = new TiffSaveOptions();

        tiff_SaveOpts.alphaChannels = true;
        tiff_SaveOpts.annotations = true;
        tiff_SaveOpts.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.JPEG;
        tiff_SaveOpts.interleaveChannels = true;
        tiff_SaveOpts.jpegQuality = 10;
        tiff_SaveOpts.layers = true;
        tiff_SaveOpts.layerCompression = LayerCompression.ZIP;
        tiff_SaveOpts.transparency = true;

        return tiff_SaveOpts;

    }
};

// Prepare dialog...
var dlg = new Window("dialog {  \
    text: 'Export layers inside the selected group', \
    alignChildren:['left','center'], \
    orientation: 'row', \
    g: Group { \
        orientation:'column', \
        alignChildren: ['left','center'], \
        filename: Panel { \
            orientation:'column', \
            alignChildren: ['left','top'], \
            filename_text: StaticText { alignment:'left', text: 'Filename ( Incremental numbers added automatically ): '}, \
            filename: EditText { alignment:'left', preferredSize: [430,20], text: '"+ docName +"', active: true },  \
        }, \
        saveAs: Panel { \
            margins: 20, \
            spacing: 20, \
            orientation: 'row', \
            alignChildren: ['left','top'], \
            saveAs_txt: StaticText { text: 'Save as: '}, \
            jpg: Checkbox { text: 'jpg', value: true }, \
            psd: Checkbox { text: 'psd', value: false }, \
            pdf: Checkbox { text: 'pdf', value: false }, \
            png: Checkbox { text: 'png', value: false }, \
            tiff: Checkbox { text: 'tiff', value: false } \
        } \
    }, \
    btns: Panel { \
        margins: 20, \
        spacing: 20, \
        orientation: 'column',  \
        alignment: ['right','top'], \
        save: Button { text: 'Save', properties:{ name: 'ok' }, preferredSize:[88, 24] }, \
        cancel: Button { text: 'Cancel', properties:{ name: 'cancel' }, preferredSize:[88, 24] }, \
    } \
}");

function makeFolder( path ) {

    var newFolder = Folder( path );
    if( !newFolder.exists ) newFolder.create();

}

if ( app.documents.length > 0 ) {
    if ( app.activeDocument.activeLayer.layers ) {

            init();

    }
    else {
        alert( "Error: \nSelect a parent group of the layers you want to export.")
    }
}
```

Comment: I can;t add the other code because it is too long for a comment and wont fit in the OP. If you can help please let me know and I can send you the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are not here to do your coding for you, but to help you with a problem with your code. What have you tried so far to combine the two scripts? Try going through each script to see what each step does, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54489426/edit) to give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is a lot of [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) online to help you figure out what the scripts you have do.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the Export As... function. In Layer Panel, select all layers/group you want to save, right click then choose Export As.... This will use layer's name to save every selected layers.

**Edit**: if you really want to do it by script, try editing these lines:

```
for( var i = 0 ; i < groupLength; i++ ){

        var layer = group.layers[ i ];
        var layerIndex = i+1;  // <-- current using Index, skip it
        var layerName = layer.name; // <-- get the Layer Name
        layer.visible = true;

        save.file( dlg, doc, getDestination, layerName ); // <-- change to layerName

        layer.visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: OP wants to do this programmatically, not using the UI.